# Exchange limit repetitive messages

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2013, rate-limiting, mailbox

Background:  We have an Avaya phone system, which has the capability of sending email alerts for a variety of scenarios.  One scenario that I am very interested in is alerts when a trunk goes down.

This works... with one major caveat:  More often than not, it will not send just one email saying that the trunk is down.  It will send emails anywhere from once/minute to several times per minute.  The result is my phone going insane with alert messages arriving in my inbox.

Each of these emails is exactly what the first one was.  Same subject, same body.

So... what I'd like is a solution to stop all the repetitive emails.  The Avaya system has no option for this.  Perhaps there is a way to do so with Exchange 2013?  Either a Mailbox server rule, or an individual rule on my Inbox.

Anyone?

Comment: What if you send the email to a service, not to you? The service would handle the repetitive messages for you and only send one alert.

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to build that on Exchange via a server based rule. You might block emails which full fill a special text sting. However in your case you need to get the first email but block all repeating emails for x hours. And this isn´t possible via out of the box (maybe there exists a 3rd party plugin which allows such kind of rules).

So I think the best option would be to setup a dedicated Monitoring environment which then send out the alarm once the issue appears but not every X min. Once possible solution which is cost free would be Nagios Core.